# Write a function that takes two arrays as parameters. The first array will be an array of people's names, and the second array will be the alphabet

Tags: javascript, loops, nested-loops

Write a function that takes two arrays as parameters.  The first array will be an array of people's names, and the second array will be the alphabet.  Using a for loop within a for loop, create and return array that looks like this:

```
function forception(people, alphabet){
 // your code here
}

var people = ["Jon", "Jacob", "Jingle", "Heimer", "Schmidt"];
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Expected Output:

> `["Jon:", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "Jacob:", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "Jingle:", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "Heimer:", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "Schmidt:", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]`

Here is my attempt:

```
var people = ["Jon", "Jacob", "Jingle", "Heimer", "Schmidt"];
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const finalArray = [];
function forception(people, alphabet) {
  const alphabetArray = alphabet.toUpperCase().split("");

  for (const name of people) {
    for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
      finalArray.push(name + alphabetArray);
    }
  }
  console.log(finalArray);
}

forception(people, alphabet);
```

But this produces:

> `['JonA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JonA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JonA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JonA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JonA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JacobA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JacobA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JacobA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JacobA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JacobA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JingleA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JingleA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JingleA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JingleA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'JingleA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'HeimerA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'HeimerA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'HeimerA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'HeimerA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'HeimerA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'SchmidtA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'SchmidtA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'SchmidtA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'SchmidtA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z', 'SchmidtA,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z']`

Answer (score 0):

Key point for this answer is the second last line of given solution below:-

```
var result = forception(people, alphabet).join(', ');
```

This **Join** function takes the array output and joins all its elements into a single string, using commas as separators. Complete code is below

```js
function forception(people, alphabet) {
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        output.push(`"${people[i]}:"`);
        for (var j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
            output.push(`"${alphabet[j].toUpperCase()}"`);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

var people = ["Jon", "Jacob", "Jingle", "Heimer", "Schmidt"];
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

var result = forception(people, alphabet).join(', ');
console.log("[" + result + "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the following line is your issue:

```
finalArray.push(name + alphabetArray);
```

You're joining `name` and `alphabetArray` into one value and adding it to `finalArray`.

`Array.push()` allows you to push multiple items:

```
finalArray.push(name + ":", alphabetArray)
```